# Direct link from google sheets to print part of the text in google docs

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have two documents:

- script in google docs with many chapters
- table in google sheets where all chapters are listed

I would like to be able to print pdf with a given chapter (various length of the chapters) with one click on the google sheets.

So far I tried with the bookmarks - it can send me directly to the beginning of the chapter in google docs, but after that i still have to print and choose pages to be printed manually.

Example of the link to the bookmark looks like this:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/edit#bookmark=id.11111xxxxxxx

Is there any way to edit the link to print the chapter?

When I create a bookmark I select part of the text, but I'm not sure if the link is to the whole selected text or just to the beggining.

Or is there any other way to solve the problem with different tool?

Any ideas??

Comment: Do you have a sample doc and sample sheet that can be used for testing? When you mean different tools, is it an add-on or script?

Comment: Google sheets - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1brawCpP_s899EDg_g3wOzD9ke1XKAGKb0Xx-9Qo4hy4/edit?usp=sharing Google docs - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_chRE5ZDYz3yPCgaEo2yWnFcjPUUVtZRj8WQ3fpETwQ/edit?usp=sharing In first column in google sheets should be links to print the corresponding chapters in google docs. The tool should be as simple as possible. I think ad-ons are ok. If no other solution possible I can also use script.

Comment: Anyone? Any idea?